# how can I create glitch effect in GIF from a normal image

Tags: ios, objective-c, after-effects, visual-glitch

create images with  different different  background image

```
   UIImage *face_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"];


   UIImage *bg_1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_1.png"];
   [bg_1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


   UIImage *bg_2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_2.png"];
   [bg_2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_3.png"];
   [bg_3 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_3 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_4.png"];
   [bg_4 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_4 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_5.png"];
   [bg_5 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_5 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_6.png"];
   [bg_6 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_6 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_7.png"];
   [bg_7 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_7 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

   UIImage *bg_8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_8.png"];
   [bg_8 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   [face_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,Width_Img, Height_Img)];
   UIImage *image_8 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

i have create 40 effected images image_1 to image_40 and put in animatedImageView

```
   animatedImageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 768, 1024)];
   animatedImageView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       Image_1,
                                       Image_1,
                                       Image_2,
                                       Image_2,
                                       bg_1,
                                       bg_1,
                                       Image_3,
                                       Image_3,
                                       Image_4,
                                       Image_4,
                                       Image_8,
                                       Image_8,
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
                                      nil];
    animatedImageView.animationDuration = 8.0f;
    animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animatedImageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

[image]

I have used multiple images to create this animated effect to view it on AnimatedImageView Controller. 
But What exactly I want is somewhat like this

But How to Create single face_image to glitch effect like Gif

[image]

Comment: hello sir , how to create glitch image not gif file ?